# more than 2 view for 1 action in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, action

I Want to have more than 2 view for 1 action in ASP.NET MVC4 so that I can based on action
I don't want to create another Action since rought value will change

the condition is based on dynamic value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the view name in the return of the action result:

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    if(yourCondition)
        return View("View1Name");
    else
        return View("View2Name");
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering View1Name and View2name is partial view name or we have to add cshtml with it